# Set submit button for ng-submit form

Tags: angularjs, form-submit

According to [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form), pressing enter in a form would "*trigger the click handler on the first button or input[type=submit] (ngClick) and a submit handler on the enclosing form (ngSubmit)*". Is there any way to instead set which button should be triggered?

I have a form in which [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) creates some button elements before the submit button.

Comment: could you catch the enter keypress and prevent the default behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `ng-submit` on the form instead of a certain button?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter how many buttons are before the submit button.

If you have `ngSubmit` directive on your form element function inside `ng-submit=""` will be fired.

For example.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="processForm()" name="myFormName">
        <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.name" placeholder="name" required="required"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.email" placeholder="email" required="required"/>

        <input type="button" value="First button" ng-click="alert('First button')"/>
        <input type="button" value="Second button" ng-click="alert('Second button')"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

When you press the 'Enter' key (in my example) angular will call `$scope.processForm` function and you will see "Submitting form.." message.

```
$scope.processForm = function(){
    alert("Submitting form..");
}
```

I've created [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7591/) example for you.

Comment: Pressing the submit button works, pressing enter on select elements work, but not input[type=text] for me..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There seems to be a problem with the fiddle: the "first button" and "second button" doesn't show an alert for me.